# Utilizar data desde la API de Coinmarketcap

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, fetch

Tengo el siguiente archivo app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

server.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
server.use(express.json());


server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fetch('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?id=1', {
        headers: {
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MYAPIKEY'
        },
        json: true,
        gzip: true
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
            return;
        }
        response.json().then(function (data) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data.data, null, 1));
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor iniciado en el puerto 3000');
});
```

El resultado me muestra la data en el navegador, todo bien en la respuesta. Ahora quiero acceder a la propiedad logo que se encuentra dentro de data, 1, urls, logo. En la siguiente imagen destaco la propiedad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero, como ejemplo básico, es mostrar esa propiedad en una etiqueta html  y establecer el source con el dato de la propiedad logo. El problema es que no me muestra esa información y si la intento encadenar por ejemplo data.data.urls.logo o data.data.1.urls.logo el primero me dice undefined y el segundo no obtengo respuesta.

```
res.send(`<img src=${data.data.urls.logo} />`);
```

Comment: El primer elemento es `1`, entonces deberías acceder con: res.send(`<img src=${data.data[1].urls.logo} />`);

Comment: No es posible hacer eso porque data no es un array de objetos.

Comment: De hecho si es posible acceder como `data[1]`, javascript sobreentiende que quieres acceder al primer elemento del objeto (en este caso es el segundo, ya que pones `1`)

Comment: Sí, fue mi equivocación. Si puedo acceder al primer objeto.